# How to update objectArray for fabric.js sortable layers when reordering #containerLayers li's

Tags: javascript, arrays, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, fabricjs

so I'm making a product using fabric - trying to add sortable layers.. But with every jsfiddle example I find, I run into the SAME issue with every one..

The issue is: After you reorder the sortable layers, when you click on any given li it highlights the wrong canvas object.

You can recreate the issue if you go to the link below this paragraph, add a couple objects, then rearrange the li's then click on one of the li's that you moved around.. it will select the wrong object (let's say you add three layers, then move the first layer you added to the top, then click the top li it will not select the proper layer but rather I think the layer that was originally there?)

https://jsfiddle.net/peLcju2h/24/

I *think* the problem might be that the objectArray array isn't updating along when rearranging the layers - so when selecting one it selects from the original order that they were in?

At this area in the code:

`

```
     $("#containerLayers").sortable({
     update: function(event, ui){

     var items = $(this).children();

     items.each(function(i,item){
                 canvas.sendToBack(objectArray[item.id]);
     });
     canvas.renderAll();
     }
     });
     $("#containerLayers").disableSelection();
```

`

I tried to put the object array  code back in the sortable code area to repopulate the array every time the li's are reordered but this didn't work for me.. I tried something like this:

`

```
     var objectArray = new Array();
     var i='0';
     var objects = canvas.getObjects();

     objects.forEach(object=>{
     var thisobject = objects[i];
     i++;
     });
     objectArray.push(thisobject);
```

`

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated!!! :)

Comment: I should note as well, that when I click on a layer after reordering.. even the wrong li highlights as well!.. So it's like the functions for the li onclick is targeting the wrong object or something?

Comment: check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/durga598/peLcju2h/63/). Do you want this?

Comment: Hey Durga, that's another good example.. But I noticed after rearranging the li's a bunch it has the same problem, not to mention that it doesn't update the layer order on the actual fabric canvas.  

Are you able to reproduce the issue that i'm speaking of?